# How do I localize Rich text in UWP Application (.NET)?

Tags: .net, xaml, localization, uwp, multilingual

I have a multilanguage UWP Application and I need to localize some text that includes formatting styles.

For example I can have this textblock:

```
<textblock x:Uid="MyText">
 <Bold>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer leo turpis, rhoncus ac libero maximus, lacinia eleifend sapien.</Bold><LineBreak/> <Italic> Aenean pulvinar eros <Underline>sit amet sodales eleifend.</Underline></Italic> <LineBreak/><Bold>Aliquam feugiat sit amet risus ac venenatis.<LineBreak/> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.<Bold><LineBreak/><Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://stackoverflow.com"> Fusce fermentum eleifend leo non pulvinar.</Hyperlink> 
</textblock>
```

To localize the textblock I create a "MyText.Text" record is resw file, but the problem is that I can't put xaml in resw.

There is a way or a pattern to localize a rich text in .NET/UWP?

Comment: [Globalization and localization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/globalizing-portal).

Comment: @IInspectable, I already read the documentation, and I localized all strings, but I'm unable to localize formatted text.

Comment: I don't understand, why formatting would make any difference. Isn't the process the same (except that you don't translate the formatting directives)?

Comment: Because if i put the xaml tags into resw they are not parsed, it prints into textblock the text with tags without formatting it.

Comment: The only way that i found to preserve formatting, is to separate every formatted sentence and traslate them one by one.
But this is not feasible because in some language the sentence order is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localize formatted XAML automatically with Uid is not possible, but dynamic XAML can be loaded via C# code from .resw files.

For example in resw I have the key `MY_FORMATTED_XAML` with this value:

```
    <Span Name="SPAN_NAME" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
      <Run>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales augue sit amet eros cursus, vitae tincidunt velit dictum. Vivamus in dolor sapien. Nunc ac dictum nulla.</Run>
      <LineBreak/>
      <Run Text="------------"/>
      <LineBreak/>
       <Run>
         Ut mollis massa ut tortor commodo cursus. Etiam at nisl eu lectus ornare iaculis. Sed consequat dignissim sapien, a tincidunt dolor rutrum at. Suspendisse accumsan eget ante ac aliquet. Nulla non dictum nisi. Nam ultrices libero ut orci pretium, finibus mollis mauris varius. Duis suscipit sapien cursus sagittis blandit. Donec hendrerit varius facilisis.                                                        
       </Run>
       <LineBreak/>
       <LineBreak/>
       <Run>
          <Bold>This is a sample for stackoverflow</Bold>
       </Run>      
       <LineBreak/>      
       <Run>      
           Nunc mollis porttitor arcu ac mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed lacinia mattis enim, a tincidunt nisi. Quisque accumsan, sapien quis fringilla pharetra, purus metus maximus velit, ac aliquam enim justo et ante. Aliquam malesuada at velit vel consequat.                
       </Run>&#160; 
<Italic>License:</Italic>
       <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://unlicense.org">Unlicense 2016.</Hyperlink>
       <LineBreak/>

    </Span>
```

In c# I have an helper class to load resources strings:

```
public static class ResourceRetriever
{
    private static ResourceMap _resourceMap = null;
    public static ResourceMap ResourceMap
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resourceMap == null)
            {
                _resourceMap=  Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap;                    
            }
            return _resourceMap;
        }
    }

    public static string GetString(string key)
    {
        return ResourceMap?.GetValue("Resources/" + key, new ResourceContext())?.ValueAsString;
    }

    public static string GetString(string key, ResourceContext context)
    {
        return ResourceMap?.GetValue("Resources/"+key, context)?.ValueAsString;
    }
}
```

And I load the dynamic xaml with this code:

```
String dynamicXaml = ResourceRetriever.GetString("MY_FORMATTED_XAML");
Span span = XamlReader.Load(dynamicXaml) as Span; 
this.MyTextBlock.Inlines.Add(span);
```